# How to disable image thumbnails from media manager but not post media uploader?

Tags: uploads

I'm trying to use the script below in order to disable automatic thumbnail generation when images are uploaded via the media manager.

I'd like to leave the thumbnail option intact when an image is uploaded directly to a post, because that uploader gives the user the ability to specify the image size.

The problem is that it disables thumbnail options in both places. I want to allow thumbs everywhere except the media manager upload.

```
if ($pagenow == 'media-new.php' || $pagenow == 'async-upload.php'){
    add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced','disable_thumbnails');
    }

function disable_thumbnails($arr_sizes){
    if(!stristr($_POST['type'], 'image')){
        return array();
    }
    return $arr_sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understand this correctly but you should be able to check which tab is currently open by looking at `$_GET['tab']`

- upload new tab = `type`
- from url = `type_url`
- gallery = `gallery`
- media library = `library`

So you could wrap your code inside

```
if ( $_GET['tab'] != 'type' )  // do stuff
```